# Hibernate thinks that child entity fields belong to parent

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a common entity used by multiple child entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class CommonEntity {
    @Id
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Entity
public class FirstChild extends CommonEntity {
    private String firstChildField;

    public String getFirstChildField() {
        return firstChildField;
    }

    public void setFirstChildField(String firstChildField) {
        this.firstChildField = firstChildField;
    }
}

@Entity
public class SecondChild extends CommonEntity {
    private String secondChildField;

    public String getSecondChildField() {
        return secondChildField;
    }

    public void setSecondChildField(String secondChildField) {
        this.secondChildField= secondChildField;
    }
}
```

`CommonEntity`, `FirstChild` and `SecondChild` are each separate tables, with `CommonEntity.id` joining to `FirstChild.id` or `SecondChild.id`.

When trying to load `FirstChild` from the database, the HQL to select the `CommonEntity` fields thinks that `firstChildField` is part of that table, though it is part of the `FirstChild` table.

When trying to load `SecondChild` from the database, the HQL to select the `CommonEntity` fields also thinks that `firstChildField` is part of that table.

Removing the field from `FirstChild` allows `SecondChild` to be loaded fine.

Is there a way I could ensure that when loading the Parent SuperClass CommonEntity it doesn't use the child fields in the FirstChild or SecondChild subclass?

EDIT:
Getting the entity from the database:

```
String hql = "from org.example.CommonEntity + " where id = ?;
List<Object> objects = getHibernateTemplate().find(hql, new Object[] { id });
```

Comment: Could you post a HQL example?

Comment: Have edited the question to include it

Comment: Don't try to load CommonEntity. That is an abstract entity. Load First or SecondChild directly.

Comment: This is adding a new child to existing code. Existing children work fine, the new one doesn't, even though it is written in the same way as the existing ones

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve / what your problem is. Besides that your code doesn't even compile, it actually has nothing to do with `FirstChild` and `SecondChild`.

Comment: The code above is a simplified version of the actual code, however it shows everything I believe to be important. I didn't write it to compile, just to give an idea of the structure.
The probem I have is that one of the child entity's fields are, according to hibernate, part of the parent entity which is incorrect

Comment: Well, I see what you are saying but could you point to the documentation that says it shouldn't work this way?

Comment: I could do. However it is a rather complex database and hibernate implementation and require a lot of refactoring to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the naming convention set up in Hibernate. It was looking for fields using underscores rather than capital letters (i.e. `first_field` instead of `firstField`). This was not represented in the database and so it was not able to find the fields in the child entity.

Answer (score 0):

May be that Helps:
For my understanding is `CommoonEntity` not an Entity, because its class is `abstract` ([what is a db entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300355/what-is-a-database-entity-and-what-types-of-dbms-items-are-considered-entities)). There are no just CommonEntities, those are always ChildEntities. Hibernate can simply not instantite those.

So the `CommonEntity` should be annotated with `@MappedSuperclass` (and not with `@Entity`). See also [Entity Enheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work as CommonEntity is an entity in the database. Setting as a mapped superclass causes errors with mapping

Comment: I am a littel confused: what's your entity definition? My is close to: [what is a db entity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300355/what-is-a-database-entity-and-what-types-of-dbms-items-are-considered-entities). I will edit my answer according to that.

Comment: The entities are all tables in the database. It turned out there was an issue with the naming conventions used